# Using Elasticsearch with Mongodb-River for searching pdf

Tags: mongodb, pdf, elasticsearch

I want to search pdf files by content, but the resulting can't read properly the content of pdf file. It looks as following:

```
{
  "took": 10,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1.0,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "mongoindex",
        "_type": "files",
        "_id": "532595b8f37d5cc2d64a517d",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "content": {
            "content_type": "application/pdf",
            "title": "D:/sample.pdf",
            "content": "JVBERi0xLjUNCiW1tbW1DQoxIDAgb2JqDQo8PC9UeXBlL0NhdGFsb2cvUGFnZXMgMiAwIFIvTGFuZyhlbi1VUykgPj4NCmVuZG9iag0KMiAwIG9iag0",
            "filename": "D:/sample.pdf",
            "contentType": "application/pdf",
            "md5": "afe70f97bce7876e39aa43f71dc7266f",
            "length": 82441,
            "chunkSize": 262144,
            "uploadDate": "2014-03-16T12:14:48.542Z",
            "metadata": {}
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Could you please help me find my mistake?

Here is the link I used:
http://v.bartko.info/?p=463

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attachment has been encoded in BASE64.
You need to decode it on a client level.

Comment: thanks for your feedback...could you provide some links how to do that?

Comment: This could help https://github.com/scrutmydocs/scrutmydocs/blob/master/src/main/java/org/scrutmydocs/webapp/servlet/DownloadServlet.java#L66